# Ignore copy(reading) the row if the foreign key doesn't exist in the parent table in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
    tconst varchar(10),
    titleType text, 
    primaryTitle text,
    PRIMARY KEY (tconst)
);

CREATE TABLE crew(
  tconst varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY, 
  directors text[],
  writers text[],
  CONSTRAINT fk_crew_movies FOREIGN KEY (tconst) 
  REFERENCES movies(tconst)
);
```

I have two data files one for movies and one for crew, but when I'm copying the data from crew data file to database I'm getting an error

```
\copy movies from 'movies.tsv';
\copy crew from 'crew.tsv';
```

> insert or update on table "crew" violates foreign key constraint
>   "fk_crew_movies" DETAIL:  Key (tconst)=(tt8038822) is not present in
>   table "movies"

It's because all the data in crew doesn't have the id's in movie data. 
So I have to ignore or delete that particular data while copying, If I dump the data into other table and delete the data by using delete statement

```
DELETE FROM crew1 WHERE tconst not in (SELECT tconst FROM movies);
```

it's taking like forever. Is there any other way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases where only a few rows actually have to be deleted the following might work better as the construct used in the select is known as an anti join and recognized by the query optimizer.

```
DELETE FROM crew1
WHERE tconst IN (
    SELECT c.tconst 
    FROM crew1 c LEFT JOIN movies m ON c.const=m.const
    WHERE m.const IS NULL)
```

Version of your INSERT without sub select

```
 INSERT INTO crew 
   SELECT c.* FROM crew1 c
     JOIN movies m ON c.const=m.const
```

Comment: Hey, it worked well but why is this below statement taking forever?
INSERT INTO crew SELECT * FROM crew1 where tconst in (select tconst from movies); @Eelke

Comment: Are you using an older version of postgresql? Older versions were not so good at optimizing sub selects. 9.5 does in most cases quite well with sub selects.

Comment: See updates answer for rewrite of your insert without sub select.

Comment: No it's 10.2, will this insert statement:)